# NSTextView typingAttributes==nil for unedited text view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nsattributedstring

I have a problem with getting the "typingAttributes" for a Rich Text NSTextView that has not yet been edited.

```
[textView typingAttributes];
```

returns nil

When I type anything and delete everything, the same instruction returns correct attributes' dictionary.

Therefore my question is: is there a way to get hold of the typingAttributes for unedited NSTextView.

Comment: you can set your own typing attributes to the textView

Comment: I know that but I want to be able to get hold of the attributes which will be used when I start typing.